# How to add a div using display:none to a Collection in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I had a field that display when I select and none when the form control item it is not selected. 
The question is: When the action occur, the field is appended in a different place.

For example,

I have this collection, in my form field:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :category_contract, as: :select, collection: Administration::DeliverersHelper.options_for_enum_select(Contract, :category_contracts) %>
    </div>
```

The div that appears when a select a specific category called contract_by_modal is:

```
<div class='col-md-4' style='display:none' id='modal'>
<label> Initial KM &nbsp;
<%= f.input :initial_charge %>
</label>
```

What happens it is that I have more than one kind of contract and when a create a new contract_by_modal, the code appends on the first contract created with another kind of category contract.

This is my javascript file:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    (.company_contracts_category_contract select)
    var $divShowClass = $('.company_contracts_category_contract select').on('change', function() { 
     if (this.value == 'contract_by_modal') {
       $('#modal').show();
       console.log(this.value)
     }
     else { $('#modal').hide();
     }
  });
});
```

What I want is that the javascript append just to the contract that a choosed and always appear as selected.

Thank you very much

Comment: is't supposed to be `$(this).value` jquery version ?

Comment: @7urkm3n it is the same thing.